# how to protect the table data from accidental delete commands using trigger

Tags: database, oracle12c

I want to create a trigger which will ensure that no record can be deleted from the table until and unless we will not disable the trigger.
  please give your precious time for this concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below. This `trigger` will raise error whenever delete statement is fired on the table.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DONT_DELETE
  2       BEFORE DELETE
  3       ON TAB1
  4       FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'No delete allowed');
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from tab1;

       COL
----------
         1
         2
         3

SQL> delete from tab1 where col = 1;
delete from tab1 where col = 1
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: No delete allowed
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.DONT_DELETE", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.DONT_DELETE'
```